# Is it allowed to omit the object for multiple prepositions with the same the object

Tags: meaning

I re-write this sentence

> A cripple is a special stud located above **a window** or below a window.

as

> A cripple is a special stud located above or below a window.

in which the object "a window" right after the preposition "above " is omitted.

Is it still grammatic and clear?

The rewrite is per my intuition. Is there some explicit rules or regularities to do this kind of jobs?

Comment: Yes, the change is perfectly fine and significantly improves the sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is still grammatical and clear.  Indeed, it is better English to simplify the sentence as you have done.  Here are examples similar to yours.

> "They hunted up and down the street, many times, searching for the
>   diamond ring she had lost."

Or ....

> "He ambled in and out of clothing stores all day, looking for red
>   trousers."

The general rule above that the noun is not repeated if the verb is unchanged.

However, where the verb changes, then in many instances it is appropriate to repeat the noun.  Consider the following two examples, both of which are correct.

> "They traipsed up hills and ran down hills all day, trying to reach
>   their journey's end before dark.
>
> They traipsed up and ran down hills all day, trying to reach their
>   journey's end before dark.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The rewrite is per my intuition. Is there some explicit rules or regularities to do this kind of jobs?

Comment: @zghqh - The general rule is that the noun is not repeated.  Off the top of my head I cannot think of any instances where the noun WOULD be repeated, if the verb is the same, but maybe others can think of them!  See the examples I have proposed.

Comment: @EWalker It could be repeated for stylistic purposes, to draw out the sentence and emphasize the repetition of the action. "They hunted up the street and down the street, searching for the diamond ring." But as you indicate, for pure technical clarity, it's better to omit.

Comment: @Katy - I agree with you completely that there are cases where for emphasis or poetic effect the noun can be repeated; your rewrite is a perfect example!